# Where can I download Ubuntu for laptops?

Tags: windows, files, downloads

I have an HP DV4 Laptop and can't find the Ubuntu download. I want to remove my Microsoft Windows 7 OS instalation.

I tried looking for the download, but can't find it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Go here to download [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

Download page from ubuntu.com:
[Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Don't be concerned that is says desktop.  It works with Laptops too.

Comment: is it an iso file or exe? cause I dont know how to download it. I want to get rid of windows. So I'm trying to download ubuntu.

Comment: You will download a cd file, so an ISO, you know how to burn an ISO right?

Comment: Here's the [ubuntu.com tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)